# How to deal with a long-running synchronous method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 App calls a old .NET (*not Core*) library that works fine. Inside the library there is a method that takes one second to run. As it is not async, it blocks my application during that second, which kills concurrency. The method uses only a small fraction of CPU and memory, and mostly are disks I/O operations.

The library is closed source and I don't have access to the developer.

I guess that in .NET such an synchronous method was OK because you could stuff many threads, but how to deal with it in .NET Core where the recommendation is to match the number of threads to the CPU cores?

Edit: The application is a synchronous web application, and I need to return the result of the method to the client.

Comment: The recommendation on how many threads you should have didn’t change with .NET Core. The same recommendation applies to both .NET Framework and .NET Core. – How often does this synchronous code run? If it’s not literally always, you could just run this through the task scheduler by doing `await Task.Run(() => SyncMethod());` That will wait asynchronously without blocking the current execution.

Comment: How often does this synchronous code run? Almost always, with 10 req/s bursts sometimes.

Comment: Hm, okay. Well, you can still use the task scheduler here and just see how well this works for you. Since the operation is not long running, this should work probably fine. Otherwise, you can always decide to simply block for it as well, running it on the current thread.